# LayoutParams дублирует view

Tags: java, android, android-layout

```
PieChart mPieChart = new PieChart(getApplicationContext());
mPieChart.addPieSlice(new PieModel("Freetime", 15, Color.parseColor("#FE6DA8")));
mPieChart.**setLayoutParams**(new PieChart.LayoutParams(300, 300));
layout.addView(mPieChart);
```

Создаем View, ставим ему LayoutParams. После запуска, появляются два одинаковых View.

Если закомментировать строку **setLayoutParams**, все отображается хорошо.

Answer (score 1):

В строке

```
 mPieChart.setLayoutParams(new XXXX.LayoutParams(300, 300));
```

вместо `XXXX` вы должны указать название ближайшего класса-родителя, в который вложен `mPieChart` в вашей разметке (например, `LinearLayout`, если он внутри `LinearLayout`, `TableRow`, если он внутри `TableRow`).

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте заменить на

```
mPieChart.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
        300,
        300));
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но не работает